# How to compare elements of two generic lists in java?

Tags: java

I have two generic list of Data Type class:RequiredList & PrimaryList

```
   public class Data{
        private String dataCode;
        private String dataDesc; 

        public String getDataCode(){}

        public void setDataCode(String dataCode){}

        public String getDataDesc(){}

        public void setDataDesc(String dataDesc){}


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> primaryList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setDataCode("code" + i);
            data.setDataDesc("desc" + i);
            primaryList.add(data);
        }

        List<Data> requiredList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setDataCode("code" + i);
            data.setDataDesc("desc" + i);
            requiredList.add(data);

        }
        StringBuffer partyList = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < requiredList.size(); i++) {
            if (primaryList.size() > i
                    && !requiredList.get(i).getDataCode().equals(primaryList.get(i).getDataCode())) {
                partyList.append(requiredList.get(i).getDataDesc());
                partyList.append(",");

            }
            if(primaryList.size() <= i)
            {
                partyList.append(requiredList.get(i).getDataDesc());
                partyList.append(",");
            }           
        }
        System.out.println(partyList.toString());
    }
```

I want to compare elements of requiredList to elements of primaryList.Those elements of primaryList are not present in requiredList , they will be added in new list.Can anybody help me out?

Comment: why do not u override `equals()` method in `Data` class and call it: requiredList.get(i).equalr(arr2.get(i)); Make sure their size is the same

Comment: I have already override this method but I am not getting actual result. I want to validate primaryList from requiredList.primary List may be 0 size 1 size or more than it.I have to show only those are not present in primaryList.

Comment: or you can use the subtract method in org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

Comment: why don't you use list.contains() to tell if the object is present in the list? And you may want to use Set instead of List to store those elements.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for Data

Then

```
List<Data> newlist = new ArrayList<Data>();
for(Data data : primaryList ) {
   if(!requiredList.contains(data) ) {
       newlist.add(data);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you okay to modify primaryList then `removeAll` would do the trick

```
primaryList.removeAll(requiredList);
```

As @Subin S pointed out `equals` and `hashCode` need to be overriden for `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

> Those elements of primaryList are not present in requiredList , they
>   will be added in new list.

Look at the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) `removeAll()` or `retainAll()` methods are useful in your usecase.